# evaluate string as a conditional expression

Tags: php, eval

I have an expression which looks like this:

```
$condition = "$foo>$bar";
```

and an array which has the values for the expression elements:

```
    array(
     'foo' => 3,
     'bar' => 4
    )
```

I did the replacement, in the `$condition` string using the `str_replace()` function, but the `3>4` expression returns true.

How can I properly evaluate my `$condition` expression in a `if()` statement?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you'd want to do this, but this is technically possible. Use [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract) to import the variables from the array into the current scope. Once you have the variables, you can simply compare them as usual:

```
$values =array(
     'foo' => 3,
     'bar' => 4
);

extract($values);

$result = $foo > $bar;

if ($result) {
    echo '$foo is greater than $bar';
} else {
    echo '$foo is not greater than $bar';
}
```

---

If `$condition` is a string and you can't change it, you could use `eval()` to evaluate the expression first:

```
$condition = "$foo>$bar";
eval(sprintf('$result = %s;', $condition));

if ($result) {
    echo '$foo is greater than $bar';
} else {
    echo '$foo is not greater than $bar';
}
```

Comment: Almost correct answer, except that author have condition as string in  variable $condition. You'll have to evaluate that string with `eval()`. Needless to say, that eval() is evil especially if you have user input somehow involved in this, but ... oh well, that's what author wants :)

Answer (score 0):

If the values **"foo"** abd **"bar"** are in an array and can either be strings or integers then why not use array sorting functions to evaluate this way:

```
<?php

$values =array(
     'foo' => 'mary and john',
     'bar' => 'john and mary'
);


/**
 * This sorts the arrays by ascending order * 
 * Result: Array ( [bar] => 2 [foo] => 5 ) * 
 */ 
natsort($values);


/**
 * now run the condition 
 * To do this we check the first key, which naturally is the smallest key
 * Alternatively, we could also check the last key, the higher value
 */
$keys=array_keys($values);


$lower_key=reset($keys);
$higher_value=end($keys);

if($lower_key=='foo'){
    echo 'Foo <strong>('.$values['foo'].')</strong> is less tha Bar <strong>('.$values['bar'].')</strong>';
}
else{
    echo 'Foo <strong>('.$values['foo'].')</strong> is greater than Bar <strong>('.$values['bar'].')</strong>';
}

/**
 * This can be summarized as
 */
natsort($values);

if(reset(array_keys($values))=='foo'){
    echo 'Foo <strong>('.$values['foo'].')</strong> is less tha Bar <strong>('.$values['bar'].')</strong>';
}
else{
    echo 'Foo <strong>('.$values['foo'].')</strong> is greater than Bar <strong>('.$values['bar'].')</strong>';
}    


//Foo (mary and john) is greater than Bar (john and mary)

?>
```